# submit button onclick() event is not firing

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajs/index",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (data) {
            var output = "";
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                output += "name:" + data[i] name + "<input type='submit' class='delete' value='Delete' onClick='deleterecord(" + data[i].id + ");'><br>"

            }
            $("#result").html(output);

            // when delete button is clicked.
            //$(".delete").click(){
            function deleterecord(id) {
                    alert("sjrg")
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "ajs/",
                        type: "DELETE",
                        data: "22",
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert("success")
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("error")
                        }
                    }); // delete  ajax() closed

                } //delete click() closed
        } //success function closed
}); //ajax call closed
```

I have displayed JSON response data using .ajax method and I added delete button for each row.

Now when I click that button I need to call deleterecord(id) function, but it is not calling it. When I use the code `$(".delete").click(function())` it is working but I need onclick event so that I can use that id in my data in ajax.

I couldn't understand what went wrong

Comment: What error you getting in console? Also be sure you using the same ID in html too... Possible post you HTML part

Comment: Why do you declare a javascript function inside an ajax request?? Just define it in the <script> section as normal.

Comment: __Move__ `deleterecord` out of success callback. Place it somewhere, Where it can be access globally. Whats the use of `id` when you are not passing it.

Comment: Tell us what error you getting in console

Comment: it is not working if move my deleterecord out of success callback

Comment: I am not getting any error the function itself is not calling

Comment: you add the delete button dynamically after the dom is ready. you have to use event delegation to bind the click event on that button. use on('click', function(){ // your code })

Comment: as i mentioned i will use that id as data in  ajax call if get this function call

Comment: if i use on('click',function(){}) how i use the id in my function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because the `deleterecord()` function is not in the scope of the event raised by the click of the `input`.

A better pattern in this case is to use a delegated event. I can see you attempted this but commented it out. To pass the `id` of the specific record to delete, add a `data-*` attribute to the appended `input`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajs/index",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {  
        var output = "";
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            output += 'name: ' + data[i]name + '<input type="button" class="delete" value="Delete" data-id="' + data[i].id + '"><br>';
        }
        $("#result").html(output); 
    }
});

// delegated delete event
$("#result").on('click','.delete', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id'); // use this in the AJAX call as required
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajs/",
        type: "DELETE", 
        data: "22",     
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) { 
            alert("success")
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("error")
        }
    });
}
```

Note also that I changed the `type` of `input` from `submit` to `button`, as only 1 submit element is allowed per form.

Comment: If i use the code of yours i could even display my code

Comment: Thankyou so much Mr. Rory i used data attribute concept from yours code it worked fine. but if i call the event after ajax the function is not trigerring. but if i use it inside success it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

try this mate,

```
$(document).on('click','.delete', function(){
    // do what you want
});
```

Some time its not firing since its build after DOM ..

Answer (score 0):

Re-write your code with the delete function out of AJAX success function,

```
 $.ajax({
 url: "ajs/index",
 type: "GET",
 dataType: "JSON",
 success: function(data) {  
  var output="";
      for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
    {
           output+="name:"+data[i]name+"<input type='submit' class='delete' value='Delete' onClick='deleterecord("+data[i].id+");'><br>"

     }
     $("#result").html(output); 


   }   //success function closed
   });  //ajax call closed

// when delete button is clicked.
           //$("#result").on('click','.delete',deleterecord(id){
            function deleterecord(id){
                alert("sjrg")
                $.ajax({
                    url: "ajs/",
                    type: "DELETE", 
                    data: "22",     
                    dataType: "html",
                    success:function(data) { 
                        alert("success")
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert("error")
                    }
                }); // delete  ajax() closed

           }//delete click() closed
```

So you can call this function from your button click. And one more thing do you still want a Submit button instead you can have a simple button type.
Hope this helps...